# How to remove vertical line from plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm getting a seemingly random vertical line on my plot and I'm unsure how to remove it. Here's the code to create the plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

fig = plt.figure()

df=pd.read_csv("Resources/outmerge.csv")


print(df.head())

x='month'
y ='Count'
sns.set_style("dark", {'axes.grid' : False})
ax = sns.lineplot('month', 'Count', data=df, marker='o',markersize=8,markers=True, label='2017')
ax = sns.lineplot('month', 'Count2', data=df, marker='^',markersize=8,markers=True, label='2018')
ax.grid(False)
fname='Resources/output.png'
plt.savefig(fname, dpi=300)

plt.show()
```

And this is the resulting plot. Note the vertical line at x axis: 1. I'm running `seaborn 0.9.0`.
[image: Output even after setting grid to False]

Comment: Try this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868304/how-to-get-rid-of-grid-lines-when-plotting-with-seaborn-pandas-with-secondary

Comment: The problem seems to be in your data. Apparently you have several values for (year 2017, month 1), but not for any of the other month. So the error range is only shown for this one data point.

Comment: @Vaibhav I changed my code, but no go. thanks, the code and output are updated above.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you're right. Taking a look at `df.head()` revealed two entries for month 1. Face palm. Thanks!